# Rails routing bug in "redirect_to" and "notice" flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-routing

I need to show notice/pop ups upon hitting of a button. Similar approaches are working in other views and controllers of the app but here on this Import button things are not working since long. None of the `redirect_to` works in the controller while their similar usage in other controller works.

`routes.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: 'root'
    # resourceful routes 
    resources :oauth_clients
    resources :tenants do
      resources :sites do
        #resources :production_shifts
        resources :units do
          resources :log_data_fields, only: [:import, :create, :index, :destroy, :download_csv] do 
            get :download_csv
            # collection route 
            collection do 
              post :import #post action 
            end
          end
```

`log_data_fields_controller.rb`:

```rb
class Admin::LogDataFieldsController < Admin::BaseController
  require 'csv'

  # import request(this is gonna be a POST action)
  def import
    logger.debug("*****Testing the logger.*****")
    
    file = params[:log_data_field][:file]
    
    # return redirect_to [:admin, @tenant, @site, @unit], notice: "Only CSV please !!" unless file.content_type == "text/csv"  
    return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_url, notice: "Only CSV please !!" unless file.content_type == "text/csv"  
    
    file = File.open(file)
    csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true) 
    # csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true, col_sep: ";") 
    
    @unit = Unit.find_by_id(params[:unit_id])
    # p @unit.id 
    
    total_rows = CSV.read(file).count
    count = 1
    # binding.b

    csv.each do |row|
      tag_hash = {}
      tag_hash[:name] = row["Name"]
      tag_hash[:alias] = row["Alias"]
      tag_hash[:column_type] = row["Type"]
      tag_hash[:unit_id] = @unit.id
      tag_hash[:is_active] = row["Active"]
      # binding.b
      # p row
      logger.debug("+++++++++++Mapping++++++++++++++")
      @log_data_field = LogDataField.create(tag_hash)
      # binding.b
      if @log_data_field.save
        count += 1
        logger.debug("--------Saves--------")
        # return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), 
      else
        # return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), 
        # render :_importtags 
      end  
    end
    
    logger.debug("-------------Going down----------")
    
    if count == total_rows && count > 1
      logger.debug("-------------All succeeded----------")
      redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), flash: { :notice => "Success"}
      # flash.notice = "Success : Tags imported from CSV !"
    elsif total_rows == 0
      logger.debug("-------------All zero----------")
      flash.alert = "Import Failure : CSV cant be empty"
      render :action => 'index', :notice => "Import Failure : CSV cant be empty."
    else
      logger.debug("-------------Failed down----------")
      flash.alert = "Import Failure"
      render :action => 'index', :notice => "Import Failure"
    end

    redirect_to import_admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_url(@tenant, @site, @unit), notice:"Imported tags !"
  end
```

`_importtags.html.haml`:

```rb
%p{:style => "color: green"}= notice

= form_with model:@log_data_field, url: import_admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path, method: :post do |form|

    - if @log_data_field.errors.any?
        #error_explanation
            %h2= "#{pluralize(@log_data_field.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this log_data_field from being saved:"
            %ul
            - @log_data_field.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
                %li= message

    -# = link_to 'Download sample csv', [:admin, @tenant, @site, @unit, @log_data_field], method: :get

    = form.file_field :file, accept: ".csv"
    -# = form.file_field :file
    <br>
    <br>

    -#button.btn.primary{:type => "submit", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."}}
    %button.btn.primary{:type => "submit"}
        = "Import"
```

Comments are the things I have tried.

Sorry if you find the question or its structure very unprofessional but I am beginner and learning regularly. I need to render the view again upon hitting that `Import` button to show either any errors if availabe or success on importing tags from csv. There is also issue of notice not being visible or popping up and redirect_to not working when non-csv document is submitted in the form which should give a warning too but it is not coming.

I believe the solution will be very short or some typo or silly mistake in understanding the path vs url routes.

***EDIT*** As per `@markets` suggestion I made all the redirect_to with `return` which are used in between so the notice are working but they appear only on refresh. Still can't get them instantly on button click:

```rb
class Admin::LogDataFieldsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_tenant
  before_action :set_site
  before_action :set_unit

  require 'csv'

  # import request(this is gonna be a POST action)
  def import
    logger.debug("*****Testing the logger.*****")
    
    file = params[:log_data_field][:file]
    
    # return redirect_to [:admin, @tenant, @site, @unit], notice: "Only CSV please !!" unless file.content_type == "text/csv"  
    return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), notice: "Only CSV please !!" unless file.content_type == "text/csv"  

    file = File.open(file)
    csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true) 
    # csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true, col_sep: ";") 
    
    @unit = Unit.find_by_id(params[:unit_id])
    # p @unit.id 
    
    total_rows = CSV.read(file).count
    count = 1
    # binding.b

    csv.each do |row|
      tag_hash = {}
      tag_hash[:name] = row["Name"]
      tag_hash[:alias] = row["Alias"]
      tag_hash[:column_type] = row["Type"]
      tag_hash[:unit_id] = @unit.id
      tag_hash[:is_active] = row["Active"]
      # binding.b
      # p row
      logger.debug("+++++++++++Mapping++++++++++++++")
      @log_data_field = LogDataField.create(tag_hash)
      # binding.b
      if @log_data_field.save
        count += 1
        logger.debug("--------Saves--------")
        # return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), 
      # else
        # return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), 
        # render :_importtags 
      end  
    end
    
    logger.debug("-------------Going down----------")
    
    if count == total_rows && count > 1
      logger.debug("-------------All succeeded----------")
      return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), flash: { :notice => "Success : Tags imported from CSV !"}
    elsif total_rows == 0
      logger.debug("-------------All zero----------")
      return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), flash: { :notice => "Import Failure : CSV cant be empty"}
    else
      logger.debug("-------------Failed down----------")
      return redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_path(@tenant, @site, @unit), flash: { :notice => "Import Failure : PLease check CSV"}
    end

    redirect_to import_admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_url(@tenant, @site, @unit), notice:"Imported tags !"
  end
```

Comment: it should be `return and redirect_to admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_url `

Comment: No @Vishal it gives error `void value expression return and redirect_to admin_tenant... ^~~~~~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the forms of other components of my app I noticed that there is an issue in my `form_with` so I changed it to `form_for` helper by reading the rails docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

So here is the working code of `_importtags.html.haml` :

```
= form_for @log_data_field, url: import_admin_tenant_site_unit_log_data_fields_url do |f|
  - if @log_data_field.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %ul
        - @log_data_field.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message

  .input-field.m0
    = f.file_field :file, accept: ".csv"
    -# = f.file_field :file
  %br
  %br
  %br

  .row
    .col.s5
      %button.btn.primary{type: 'submit', data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."}}
        Save
```

There no need to specifically pass a `method: :post` either as import is already a post action defined in the routes.rb

Along with this what [@markets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3033649/markets) had suggested and answered in this thread was very helpful and accepted too. Thanks to markets for that !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `render` or `redirect_to` in the middle of a controller (not the last line), you should use `return` too in order to stop the current execution path:

```rb
return redirect_to(...)
```

or

```rb
redirect_to(...) and return
```

More info: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: THanks! Now atleast the notice are coming for other works but still only on refresh. Please help I have added the edited code in the edit section

Comment: That's another problem and you should post it in a new question (and accept this one or give some credit... as it seems it solves one of your original issues). 

The current question is too much large and probably no-one will be able to understand the current situation and all the "updates" made in the OP.

Comment: Okay fine I accepted alright but still the major part of the question is "Notice not popping up on instant button click". I still need help in that so I have accepted your answer partially and I am grateful to increase your stackOverflow reputation sir. And if you did not understood my question then I am sorry for my poor construction as I am trying to provide everything related to issue so that no gap is left in coveying the source the problem. Looking forward to a solution.

Comment: No prob sir! But the current question is probably too much large to understand it and have all the context in mind, taking into account the updates made. Now that we solved the main problem, you can post a "focused" (short, but with all relevant info) new question about the flash messages, pretty sure someone will help you (I'll also take a look if you provide me the link).

Comment: Yup thanks alot for your help I realised many rails concepts and found the solution which I have answered here for this question :D